# How can I integrate hasura postgre data into an existing Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, heroku-postgres, hasura

I have an existing Wordpress website and want to fetch data from a hasura postgre. Anyone try this yet?

Comment: Since you can run Javascript in Wordpress, don't see why not! https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-javascript/

Comment: You can create a custom plugin and fetch the data using the Hasura GraphQL endpoint. You can do pretty much anything you want.